# CSS Float with blocks

Tags: css

I have a problem, how i can fix blocks?

1. Block Sidebar

   ```
   .sidebar {
       display: block;
       width: 250px;
       float: left;
       height: 100%;
       background-color: #2b2b2b;
       margin-right: 15px;
   }
   ```
2. Block Content

   ```
   .content-panel {
       margin-right: 15px;
       margin-top: 15px;
   }
   ```

Problem: 
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gBgF.png)

How i can fix content block? I have to make sure that the unit does not take into account the width of the sidebar, while its width is 100%, and sidebar 250px

Comment: try to add float left to `.content-panel` too, if i understand your question.

Comment: please provide more info

Comment: I can't add float: right to content-panel, because he don't have width

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `display:table` or `display:flex` would be the way to go here, if you provided your html structure for the content and sidebar and their parent then we may be able to give you a better answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
.content-panel {
    width: calc(100% - 280px);
    margin-left: 265px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
```

That width subtracts the width of the sidebar and all the margins from 100%, the margin-left moves it to the right.

Comment: Yep, I was going to suggest using calc too but you were faster =)

Comment: Thanks, are how i can add margin-right to .content-panel > 15px? If i add, then nothing happens

Comment: There is already a margin-right in that rule. Do you really need a margin (there is nothing right of that panel)? What do you expect to happen?  Or rather a padding-right instead?

Comment: I want to change margin-right: 15px to margin-right: 20px

Comment: then change `width` to `calc(100% - 285px);`The substracted value is the sum of the sidebar width plus all right and left margins in both elements.

Comment: I did everything, nothing changed

Comment: then you should include some more code (also HTML) and possibly also a codepen or JSfilddle in your question.

Comment: And when I do a small screen, width not 100% and have the margin-left: 265px, how i can remove this ?

Comment: what you gave does not work adaptively, margin-left: 265px there should be no

Answer (score 0):

You can also use just `margin-left` to get content block width `100% - 250px`:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.sidebar {
  background: lightblue;
  float: left;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 250px;
}

.content {
  margin-left: 250px;
  padding: 16px;
  height: 100vh;
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar"></div>
<div class="content">Content</div>
```